# Spring Boot + Angular file upload unable to upload same file twice

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

Error under Network in chrome

```
{ timeStamp: ......, status: 400
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: 'Required request part 'file' is not present'
  path: 'url as hosted on Tomcat'
}
```

Spring Boot Controller.java file

```
@PostMapping("/Post")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") 
MultipartFile file){ String Message=""; try .......(and so on)}
```

My Angular Component

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
<input type="file" id="selectFile" formControlName="file1" name="selectFile"
(change)="fileEvent($event)"/>

<input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Component.ts file

```
fileEvent(e) {
 this.data = e.target.files[0];
}
omSubmit() {
  let headers: any = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-type', 'undefined');
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("selectFile", this.data);
  const req5 = new HttpRequest('POST', 'url as hosted on TOMCAT', formData,
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'text'
  });
  return this.httpClient.request(req5).subscribe(e => {(
  console.log(e);
  )}
}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
formData.append("selectFile", this.data);
```

to that:

```
formData.append("file", this.data);
```

Cause

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file")
```

Comment: I marking this as answer since it resolved my query :)

Comment: Thanks @Simon wanted to know reason behind this change so that i can upgrade my knowledge too

Comment: public ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file")) is expecting the file from the request to be accessible via request parameter "file"
formData.append("file", this.formData) would do that for you

Comment: Hey, i thought your exception explains everything ;) With @RequestParam("file") you define that this method requires an input which is named "file". Here "formData.append("selectFile", this.formData);" you define that your formdata will be transferred named "selectFile". This just doesn't match. So your ex ception "'Required request part 'file' is not present" tells you, that the method expect a "file", which is not there cause it is named "selectFile". Have a nice day :)

Comment: thanks @Simon once again, please have a look to my below query once 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463810/spring-boot-angular-xlsx-file-upload-http-417-error

Comment: please help me on my below query its similar to this @Simon - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515500/spring-angular-unable-to-upload-same-file-twice

Comment: not getting idea how to resolve it please help me @Simon on this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515500/spring-angular-unable-to-upload-same-file-twice

Answer (score 1):

Param annotation in your controller looks for a field called *file*.

Change **selectFile** to **file** will solve the problem.

```
formData.append("file", this.data);
```

Parameter name matters in this, it has to be same in both `Java` & `Angular`

Comment: thanks @noiaverabale - replacing 'selectFile' to 'file' worked but changing Content-Type from undefined to 'multipart/form-data' produced

       Http - 417 error

Comment: My bad, I mistake content-type with enctype. I'll edit my response, thank you.

Comment: no problem any way thanks for help from your side too

Comment: Hi @noiaverabale - please have look to my query i guess its similar to what you commented earlier   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463810/spring-boot-angular-xlsx-file-upload-http-417-error