# FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet' need to handle many requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

Spring + Angular file upload. At a moment able to upload only file when trying to upload another file getting HTTP - 417 error.

Plus on tomcat after starting server after 1st upload i am receiving following message -

```
  FrameworkServlet dispatcherServlet initialization started
  FrameworkServlet dispatcherServlet initialization completed in 114ms
```

Hence to upload another file i have to start the server again.

Whats the solution to this to allow server handle many requests. If code is required let me know i will post my Spring and Angular files.

Comment: Have you used REST-API to transfer the file?

Comment: @iamrajshah - yes please have a look to my below resolved query holding my application code files too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462480/spring-boot-angular-file-upload-getting-error-400-bad-request

Comment: Once you host your war file i.e, Once *completed in XXms* cames you can call it N no of times. Can you tell me when you try to upload another file what exactly you mean? and code for the second attempt

Comment: @iamrajshah i mean to say suppose i uploaded one file it is sent to server and i am getting HTTP 200, now on the same page when i am selecting another file to upload again i am getting HTTP - 417 error

Comment: @iamrajshah is there issue on UI side on Angular regarding headers or something ??

Comment: Yes I think so. Can you paste code somewhere?

Comment: @iamrajshah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462480/spring-boot-angular-file-upload-getting-error-400-bad-request

Can you check this it is having all set of codes of my application

Comment: Still if you want i can post here also ...

Comment: No I have check that. I think you are clicking button twice right? by changing file??

Comment: @iamrajshah no i am clicking it once but i guess you caught the issue maybe the Formdata might be already having previous file after sending to server then after selecting another file it might be having more than 1 file.. am i right ?

Comment: Exactly this will be the issue. If you are trying again to send file just clear formdata and try again. It will solve

Comment: @iamrajshah do you any specific syntax to clear formData that will help me here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187736/discussion-between-olivia-and-iamrajshah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset your `formData` when you try to upload second file.

```
 public formdata = new FormData(); 
    onSubmit() { 

    this.resetform();  //Order matters here
    let headers: any = new Headers(); 
    headers.append('Content-type', 'undefined'); 

    formData.append("selectFile", this.formData); 
    const req5 = new HttpRequest('POST', 'url as hosted on TOMCAT', formData, 
    reportProgress: true, 
    responseType: 'text' 
    }); 
    return this.httpClient.request(req5).subscribe(e => {( 
    console.log(e); 

    )} 
    } 

    resetform() { 
    this.formData = new FormData(); 
    }
```

I hope it will solve your problem !!!

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for appreciation

Comment: i am not bale to upload same file more than once @iamrajshah following above changes, any resolution to it ?

Comment: @Olivia are you trying on same iteration or on different iteration?

Comment: It will upload same file, I think you have mistaken something. Please paste code

Comment: please have a look to this @iamrajshah, expecting answer from you on my below query...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515500/spring-angular-unable-to-upload-same-file-twice